# LINQ query for removing all objects with an id not equal to a list of ids now workign properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In the `var workrolesusersdetailsQuery` after filtering I get a list of three `int?` ids. After that in the foreach loop I am simply trying to remove all the objects with id's not equal to the above mentioned id's. As a result it removes all the objects. The interesting part is that if i replace the `!=` with `==` then it is working properly.

I just don't see what am i doing wrong, so, please, can somebody help?

```
var workrolesusersdetailsQuery = db.WorkRolesUsersDetails
            .Where(m => m.UserDetailsId == currentUserId && m.isActive == true)
            .Select(m => m.WorkRoleId).ToList();//select only thw workroleid column

        foreach (var wr in workrolesusersdetailsQuery)
        {
            var temp = wr;
            WorkRolesQuery.RemoveAll((x) => x.WorkRoleId != wr);

        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without `Foreach` use this

```
WorkRolesQuery.RemoveAll((x) => !workrolesusersdetailsQuery.Contains(x.WorkRoleId));
```

Comment: How can I use the 'wr' part without the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I think your delete may also be done using [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended):

```
WorkRolesQuery
    .Where(x => !workrolesusersdetailsQuery.Contains(x.WorkRoleId));
    .Delete();
```

The main advantage over provided solution is that, a single `DELETE` statement will be issued against the database. For a large amount of deleted items, gained performance is large.

However, a `TransactionScope` is needed if this delete should be part of a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in workrolesusersdetailsQuery.Where(x => !WorkRolesQuery.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID)).ToList())
{
enter code here
}
```

same work you also can do with `Contains`

secondly `Where` is give you new list of values.
you can achieve your target from `Any` and `contains` like
Hope this will clear your confusion.